# Add null occurring levels to dataset in R

Tags: r

Say I have the following data, which gives the summary

```
 summary(mydata)
 1   2   3   4   8   9  10  11  12 
 11  45  25   3  23  52 126   2   4
```

and

```
levels(mydata)
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12"
```

where the `levels` represent impact direction according to 12 oclock orientation.

How can I add null occuring factors?
ie. 5,6,7

Comment: `levels(x) <- c(levels(x), 5:7)` if you mean you want to add them in.  But numeric vectors usually aren't factored??

Comment: Or `levels(x) <- seq_len(12)`

Comment: @RichardScriven, his data is factored as the `levels` function works properly.

Comment: or `levels(x) <- 1:12` :P

Comment: @RichardScriven, how is it better than `seq_len(12)`?

Comment: Its 7 less characters. :p